# Exception in thread "main" after program runs

Tags: java, string, exception, indexoutofrangeexception

My program is a game to determine how many legs a certain animal (dog/chicken/fish) has.

Every time I run the program, I get an error message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at AnimalGame.main(AnimalGame.java:67)".
```

I can't find the problem. Also, I want the program to end after it says "You win!" or "You lose!", but each time it says one of those outputs, it then says

> "I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char n = 0;
    char y = 0;
    char gameAnswer = 'n';

    do
    {
    System.out.println("Choose an animal: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();

        switch (text) {
        case "dog":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a dog have?");
            int dg = input.nextInt();

            if(dg == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

        case "chicken":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a chicken have?");
            int chkn = input.nextInt();

            if(chkn == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

        case "fish":
            System.out.println("How many legs does a fish have?");
            int fsh = input.nextInt();

            if(fsh == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
    }
    System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
    gameAnswer = input.nextLine().charAt (0);
    }while(gameAnswer == 'y');
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you have a white-space between charAt and (0). Try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Nope. It still gives the same message, @Cfrim .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few problems, main one was that when the user enters the number of legs he presses "enter" which adds a newline character right after the int, but since only the int is being read, the newline is being buffered and used on the next read which messes up everything.

The solution to that is to add a `readLine()` at the end of each `case` just before the `break`.

Another issue was that the line:

```
System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
```

was always printed regardless if the animal was known or not. For that - an addition of a `known` boolean parameter fixed the issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char gameAnswer = 'y';

    do {
        System.out.println("Choose an animal: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        boolean known = false;
        switch (text) {
            case "dog":
                System.out.println("How many legs does a dog have?");
                int dg = input.nextInt();

                if (dg == 4) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
                }
                known = true;
                input.nextLine();
                break;

            case "chicken":
                System.out.println("How many legs does a chicken have?");
                int chkn = input.nextInt();

                if (chkn == 2) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
                }
                known = true;
                input.nextLine();
                break;

            case "fish":
                System.out.println("How many legs does a fish have?");
                int fsh = input.nextInt();

                if (fsh == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
                }
                known = true;
                input.nextLine();
                break;

            default:
                break;    
        }
        if (!known) {
            System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
            String tmp = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                gameAnswer = tmp.charAt(0);
            }
        }    
    } while (gameAnswer == 'y');    
}
```

Now that we have the code working, it might be a good idea to do some refactoring. I took a few steps and it could probably be improved even further:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char gameAnswer = 'y';

    do {
        System.out.println("Choose an animal: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();
        boolean known = getLegs(input, text);
        if (!known) {
            System.out.println("I don't know that animal. Do you want to try again? (y/n)");
            String tmp = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                gameAnswer = tmp.charAt(0);
            }
        }
    } while (gameAnswer == 'y');

}

private static boolean getLegs(Scanner input, String animal) {
    boolean known = identifyAnimal(animal);
    if (known) {
        System.out.printf("How many legs does a %s have?\n", animal);
        int legs = input.nextInt();
        if (checkDog(animal, legs) || checkChicken(animal, legs) || checkFish(animal, legs)) {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        }
        /*
        known = true;
        input.nextLine();
        */ 
        return; // since the OP stated in the comments that he wants the code to exit here.
    }
    return known;
}

private static boolean identifyAnimal(String animal) {
    return "dog".equals(animal) || "chicken".equals(animal) || "fish".equals(animal);
}

private static boolean checkDog(String animal, int legs) {
    return legs == 4 && "dog".equals(animal);
}

private static boolean checkChicken(String animal, int legs) {
    return legs == 2 && "chicken".equals(animal);
}

private static boolean checkFish(String animal, int legs) {
    return legs == 0 && "fish".equals(animal);
}
```

Comment: Alright almost got it! Now after the output "You win!" or "You lose!" comes out, the program is supposed to terminate. Instead, after those outputs, it again asks to "Choose an animal:".

Comment: In that case - simply add a `return;` after you print the win/lose notification. BTW, I'm going to add some suggestions for refactoring in a minute. Stay tuned.